# Chart.JS não aparece no modal bootstrap!

Tags: modal

Quero mostrar estatísticas sobre quais as porcentagens de cada resposta dada em uma pergunta de uma pesquisa que estou projetando aqui.
Estudei e vi vários tutoriais sobre como usar o Charts.JS. Funciona normalmente se crio uma página independente. Mas neste caso particular preciso que o gráfico (em formato de Pizza) apareça em um Modal do Bootstrap. Mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum. O modal fica em branco e apenas o gráfico de linha da própria documentação do Chart.JS funciona.

Estou utilizando o seguinte codigo:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">$('#ModalPadrao3').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
var option = {
    responsive: true,
};
    var data = [
    {
            value: 300,
            color:"#F7464A",
            highlight: "#FF5A5E",
            label: "Red"
    },
    {
            value: 50,
            color: "#46BFBD",
            highlight: "#5AD3D1",
            label: "Green"
    },
    {
            value: 100,
            color: "#FDB45C",
            highlight: "#FFC870",
            label: "Yellow"
    }
];
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx,{type: 'pie', data: data, options: option});
});
</script>
```

O que há de errado que só aparece uma área em branco mas sem o gráfico que eu programei?

Answer (score 3):

Ao meu ver, parece que ao setar o valor Data está ocorrendo erro. Criei um exemplo funcional a partir da [documentação](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html). Veja como ficou:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ModalPadrao3').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    var option = {
      responsive: true,
    };

    var config = {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
          ],
          backgroundColor: [
            'red',
            'orange',
            'yellow',
            'green',
            'blue',
          ],
          label: 'Dataset 1'
        }],
        labels: [
          "Vermelho",
          "Laranja",
          "Amarelo",
          "Verde",
          "Azul"
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalPadrao3" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir modal</button>

<div id="ModalPadrao3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Título</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer no modal. Creio que este sistema que estou gerenciando tem alguma particularidade ou então não está importando corretamente os jQuery. Pior que não posso mexer porque senão desconfigura todo o site. Tive que fazer numa página separada mesmo. Mas o tamanho do gráfico está 1550px de largura e altura mesmo eu forçando um numero menor. O que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

@WitnessTruth sobre o seu problema do tamanho do gráfico, tive um problema similar e consegui resolver incluindo um style dentro da  tag **canvas**

```html
<canvas id="myChart" style="height:40vh; width: 100%"></canvas>
```